# Move a child div to the end in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to the world of CSS/JS/HTML. I read a few posts on how to reposition the *divs*, but they are were contained within the same parent div container. In my scenario, I need to move one of the inner divs to end of the page.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block-row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="richtext">
             Some Text
          </div>

          <ul class="list clearfix">
            <li class="list-item">
              List item 1 text
            </li>
            <li class="list-item">
              List item 2 text
            </li>
          </ul>  

          <div class="richtext">
            <p>Some text that needs to appear at the bottom of the page in mobile view only</p>    
          </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="col-70 sidebar">
            <div class="info">     
              <h2 class="info-head">
                <span>Text</span> text
              </h2>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to move div with class *richtext* that appears after the *`<ul>`* element, after the div with class *sidebar* in the mobile view of the page.

Is CSS or JS the way to go for it? What would be the best and the most elegant approach for it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have more of those elements on a single page? If yes than you should mention it - cause there's a huge difference in doing a job for one element (usually helpful to use ID in such case) or doing it for more than one element.

Comment: Hi Roko, there are 2 divs with class richtext on the page. One of them needs to be moved out to the end of the page, as mentioned. There are more <div class="container"> on the page but they have different child elements.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use to use jquery's function `insertBefore()`.

```js
if($(window).width() >= 768)
      $("ul + .richtext").insertBefore(".sidebar");
 else
      $(".sidebar").insertBefore("ul + .richtext");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="block-row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="richtext">
             Some Text
          </div>

          <ul class="list clearfix">
            <li class="list-item">
              List item 1 text
            </li>
            <li class="list-item">
              List item 2 text
            </li>
          </ul>  

          <div class="richtext">
            <p>Some text that needs to appear at the bottom of the page in mobile view only</p>    
          </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="col-70 sidebar">
            <div class="info">     
              <h2 class="info-head">
                <span>Text</span> text
              </h2>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use `.insertBefore($(".sidebar"))` instead of `.insertBefore(".sidebar")` - also are you sure that pointing to a class is good? Also why only on `resize`? Is that enough? Probably creating a function and than calling it when needed would be better

Comment: Why do you use `e.preventDefault()` what default browser behavior are you trying to prevent on resize?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thnx for pointing out.. You can use .insertBefore(".sidebar") without any problem. And yes, e.preventDefault() is not required.

Comment: :) glad I could point something out. P.S: Imagine you're on a large project. You have N scripts that do expensive tasks on resize, but use the `window.onresize` event wisely. By doing `.resize()` you're triggering all those evens at-once. I repeat, you should better go for a function, encapsulate your code, and call it like `$(moveRichText) // DOM ready` and `$(window).on("load resize", moveRichText)` << and making sure you use some call throttling to leverage the work JS does on window resize... but that's just being too picky I guess?!

Comment: I see <span>Text</span> text displayed twice when I run the snippet.

Comment: @Sitecorenovice I have updated the answer so that the script only runs once when the page loads and based on the size of the browser it display richtext class in its appropriate position.

Comment: @Raj are you sure `$(".sidebar").insertBefore(".richtext");` is correct?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes I executed the code and checked it..It works correctly.

Comment: @Raj  that's not the way to do it than. I'd also suggest you to re-read the question. OP wants to *move* only one element.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes but i am moving only one element(ul + .richtext) in my code. Please check it.

Comment: it does not work on resize. If you wrap your code into such event you'll see what happens. If I'm on desktop and I want to check out a responsive page on mobile size - your code should work, not introduce bugs :) - PS read also my direct comment on OP's question.